# decimal type property adds a zero to the textbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a **MVC4** application, type of one of properties is `decimal`, when it loads the view it adds a *zero* to the *textbox*.

**How can I make the textbox to be empty when it loads first time?**

```
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    [Display(Name ="Amount")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must add amount")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is showing a zero the first time is loads because you are not populating the model with anything.  So, the ViewEngine inserts the "default" value of a decimal type, which is a zero.

To make it not show anything, you would need to make your decimal property nullable.

```
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[Column(TypeName = "money")]
[Display(Name ="Amount")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must add amount")]
public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
```

Now, the view engine will see the default as null and create an empty textbox.